# How to list out all values from the get_body_class array

Tags: functions, body-class

I am trying to list out all of the current page body classes. using the `body_class` function it gave me `class="[body classes were here]"` however I need to show these as plain text. I have tried the `get_body_class` function however it is an array.

How would I go about pulling the current page/post body classes from this?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_body_class

Current Code:

```
$parentTitle = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
$parentID = get_the_ID($post->post_parent);
$currentTitle = get_the_title($post);
$currentID = get_the_ID();
$bodyclasses = get_body_class($post);
    foreach ($bodyclasses as $currentBodyClass)
echo "
<div id='plugin-PageInfo' class='clearfix'>
    <div id='plugin-PageInfo-click'>
        <i class='fa fa-cog'></i>
    </div>
    <div id='slideOutContainer'>
        <div id='slideContent'>"
        . $parentTitle . $parentID . $currentTitle . $currentID . $currentBodyClass .
        "</div>
    </div>
</div>
";
```

Amended, Working Code:

```
$parentTitle = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
$parentID = get_the_ID($post->post_parent);
$currentTitle = get_the_title($post);
$currentID = get_the_ID();
$bodyclasses = get_body_class($post);

echo "
<div id='plugin-PageInfo' class='clearfix'>
    <div id='plugin-PageInfo-click'>
        <i class='fa fa-cog'></i>
    </div>
    <div id='slideOutContainer'>
        <div id='slideContent'>"
        . $parentTitle . $parentID . $currentTitle . $currentID .''; 
        foreach ($bodyclasses as $currentBodyClass) {
    echo "$currentBodyClass<br />\n";
}    
    echo    "</div>
    </div>
</div>
";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bodyclasses = get_body_class();
foreach ($bodyclasses as $class)
        echo $class;
```

Comment: I only seem to get this output using that: `no-customize-support`

Comment: I had to amend slightly but got it working using: `foreach ($bodyclasses as $currentBodyClass) {
    echo "$currentBodyClass<br />\n";
}`